# How do Linux distributions check the CD/DVD-ROM integrity?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

For example in Debian Wheezy installation CD there is a *"Check the CD-ROM(s) integrity"* menu option in debian-installer main menu. Checking the integrity of CD takes few minutes. How are such tests usually done? By simply reading all the files from CD and in case thee are no read errors from file-system, the CD is valid? Or does it involve some sort of hash calculation and comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking from an Ubuntu 14.10 ISO I had here, there is a `md5sums.txt` file in the root directory of the CD. The file has the MD5 sum of the files.

```
cde56251d6cae5214227d887dee3bab7  ./pics/red-upperleft.png
0730e775a72519aaa450a3774fca5f55  ./pics/red-lowerleft.png
cd8aa5e7fa11b1362ef1869ac6b1aa56  ./pics/blue-lowerleft.png
92091902d3ca753bb858d4682b3fc26b  ./pics/logo-50.jpg
461cbc7ff94fdea8008cab34b611abb8  ./pics/blue-upperright.png
```

Then the installer can compute the checksums of all the files on the CD and compare them against the contents of this file.

Just reading all files from the CD wouldn't catch a corrupted ISO that was burned successfully.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. On Debian Wheezy installation CD for x86 architecture there is also a md5sum.txt file(2593 lines) which lists the MD5 hashes of those very same files seen checked during the CD-ROM integrity test.